# Applying aggregate function to every column of certain type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I wrote the basis (that doesnt work) on how to average every FloatType column in my data frame like so:

```
val descript = df.dtypes

  var decimalArr = new ListBuffer[String]()
  for(i <- 0 to (descript.length - 1)) {
    if(descript(i)._2 == "FloatType") {
      decimalArr += descript(i)._1
    }
  }

  //Build Statsitical Arguments for DataFrame Pass
  var averageList = new ListBuffer[String]()
  for(i <- 0 to (decimalArr.length - 1)){
    averageList += "avg(" + '"' + decimalArr(i) + '"' + ")"
  }

  //sample statsitical call
  val sampAvg = df.agg(averageList).show
```

The example that gets produced by averageList is:

```
ListBuffer(avg("offer_id"), avg("decision_id"), avg("offer_type_cd"), avg("promo_id"), avg("pymt_method_type_cd"), avg("cs_result_id"), avg("cs_result_usage_type_cd"), avg("rate_index_type_cd"), avg("sub_product_id"))
```

The clear problem is that val sampAvg = df.agg(averageList).show does not allow listBuffer as the input. So even bringing it .toString doesnt work it wants org.apache.spark.sql.Column*. Does anyone know a way I can do something in the manner I am trying.

Side Note I am on Spark 1.3

Comment: Have you tried sc.parallelize on averageList and then .toDF() functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first build a list of the aggregate expressions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, avg, lit}

val exprs = df.dtypes
  .filter(_._2 == "DoubleType")
  .map(ct => avg(col(ct._1))).toList
```

and either pattern match

```
exprs match {
  case h::t => df.agg(h, t:_*)
  case _ => sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
}
```

or use a dummy column

```
df.agg(lit(1).alias("_dummy"), exprs: _*).drop("_dummy")
```

If you want to use multiple functions you can `flatMap` either explicitly:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{avg, min, max}

val funs: List[(String => Column)] = List(min, max, avg)

val exprs: Array[Column] = df.dtypes 
   .filter(_._2 == "DoubleType")
   .flatMap(ct => funs.map(fun => fun(ct._1)))
```

or using for comprehension:

```
val exprs: Array[Column] = for {
    cname <-  df.dtypes.filter(_._2 == "DoubleType").map(_._1)
    fun <- funs
} yield fun(cname)
```

Convert `exprs` to `List` if you want to use pattern match approach.

Comment: Question why would val exprs = df.dtypes
  .filter(_._2 == "DoubleType")
  .map(ct => avg(col(ct._1))).toList work but if I break it up  val exprs = df.dtypes.filter(_._2 == "DoubleType") and val avg = exprs.map(ct => avg(col(ct._1))).toList wil not? I plan on doing min and max as well so I wanted to split up the mappings and combine into one large aggregation if that makes sense.

Comment: Because if you use `val avg = exprs.map(ct => avg(col(ct._1))).toList` you get a recursive call (note `avg` on LHS and RHS) and it is messing with compiler big time.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for such a detailed explanation. Is there any way we can apply aggregation on all numeric columns like `IntegerType`, `Doubletype`.

Comment: @agnes In Scala? Other than enumeration? Not a one I am aware of. There is no common hierarchy for fractional  and integral types and base objects are private.

Comment: @zero323 Yes In scala. Because Lets say the way I automate and customize `describe()` to compute stats of all columns of dataframe whether its string or numeric. If there would have been a hierarchy the I can do the `agg` on all `numeric` columns alltogether. Instead the way now I have to hardcode every other sql data type.

Comment: @agnes I am afraid I don't have anything to add. Still, there roughly four numeric classes in use (bigint,  float, int, double, decimal)  to six (if you count byte and short) numerics. There also SQL conversions but this is completely different story.

Comment: @zero323 Sure! Thank for your help.